# split a string message into array in Typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I'm trying to split a string message into array in Typescript. I cannot use comma as there's a json string. I tried to parse but I'm getting an error.

```
const msgs = 'string_no_quotes,"string-with@}-weirdchars",{"ckey":null,"email":"user@gmail.com","pass":"password","name":{"firstName":"User","middleName":"","lastName":"Name"},"address":{"street": "test street", "country":"some country", "zip": "639821"},"status":1},opt-data'

const messages:string[] = JSON.parse(msgs.toString())
```

The error :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

What could be a best solution to get values in to string array.

PS: If you wonder why I came up with such nasty string, its 'ZeroMQ' message. And, i tried,

```
JSON.parse("["+msgs.toString()+"]")
eval("("+msgs.toString()+")")
```

Comment: Hey Cosmo. What do you want the final data structure to look like?

Comment: The string you're using is not valid JSON (it's not even a valid JS/TS string) so I guess the best solution is to pass it valid JSON. Otherwise you'll need to write a custom parser to go through the string and whenever it encounters a comma to determine what's coming next and read that accordingly.

Comment: Your first line of code is not valid. You have a string `'string_no_quotes,"string-withQuotes",'` and then an object `{"ckey"...`

Comment: an array of string objects ["string_no_quotes", "string-withQutoes", "{/*JSON string*/}", "opt-data"].  I understand that JSON.parse trying to parse the string as object but I want that object inside the array preferably parsed. Thanks jburtondev

Comment: Is it at all possible that you could change the data source to send properly formatted JSON instead? That would almost certainly be easier than dealing with this.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery : the data is received as buffer from zmq broker and when used msg.toString(), I get this message string

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out with a custom func after a long tryout, not a straight forward, but works as needed. The original problem was the input is received as a buffer from zmq broker and there's that weird format of data from msg.toString()

Steps:

1. Used a regex to segregate the object data,
2. replace the regex match with template string,
3. split it, replace the 'made' array and return it.

   ```
    export const parseTheCrapOutOfThatDamnString = (paramString: string) => {
      const regEx = RegExp("(?<={)(.*)(?=})") //(?<={)(.*)(?=})  //https://regexr.com/2tr5t
      if(regEx.test(paramString)) { 
        var theMatch:string = `${_.head(paramString.match(regEx))}` || "" //;console.log(`\n${theMatch}\n`)
        var paramsArray = _.replace(paramString, theMatch, "replaceable").split(',') //;console.log(paramString)
        paramsArray[paramsArray.indexOf('{replaceable}')] = JSON.parse(`{${theMatch}}`)
        return paramsArray;
      }else { 
        return JSON.parse("["+paramString+"]")
      }
    }
   ```

the call,

```
  const msgs = 'string_no_quotes,"string-with@}-weirdchars",{"ckey":null,"email":"user@gmail.com","pass":"password","name":{"firstName":"User","middleName":"","lastName":"Name"},"address":{"street": "test street", "country":"some country", "zip": "639821"},"status":1},opt-data'
  console.log(parseTheCrapOutOfThatDamnString(msgs))
```

the final output:

```
["string_no_quotes", "string-with@}-weirdchars", {
  "ckey": null,
  "email": "user@gmail.com",
  "pass": "password",
  "name": {
    "firstName": "User",
    "middleName": "",
    "lastName": "Name"
  },
  "address": {
    "street": "test street",
    "country": "some country",
    "zip": "639821"
  },
  "status": 1
}, "opt-data"]
```

here it is [Typescript play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKABAxg9gdgzgFzABwIYCc4FMAqALLAYXVWQHkBXBMgM31QQBFUBbGAZQXQEsYBzMAF4wACjQkWnHvwBcYRNL4BKIQD4wAb1BgdYAPR6RAfgA8gjUpEA6AFSWjggL4r9evAgTI4Mg+ix8sAA90K2gWPQAmLgBWBG1daHgkPz4AUUChMAAlf3TkEQAiYzMLaztjJyUCpXidbhoRFPSrBCxEMQxWKV5lFQ0wWt0ANwwwBAIAWQYIPBkFHsyAAwASDXEurh6rFmm8RtzApSs4PHqEESVHRbAAHxuwAoLBnXXJTf5M1+7+Kz9kABtUBAsCJxlgpggZgAaB5-QHA1AAI3+WGqzzAI3QKE6LDgAEF0CQAJ6fHHfPjHAHcc4AcihNJq4F0OnRr3xhNQRIA2myCcSrLwACZBWgiGkaOFArBIlGOBkAXUyACl2GQAHJWcTYESLDSrMEQmaOK6M5k6PwICjoGDYiTs4kAbkGjiw-2wmgGTOZFqtNpV6s1GG1BS5BQA1F93nwwwV5WivWBHLUkyB4olEGBcXw4JkafN+AB9GBQAsARwoUFacChBXzfAAtAB3al4AACjibWG46EFMyDBShGgKEAA1lgiQUZDAKP9-jWsDtuP9JwUKNh0K2+Iv-qEoCwBwU0HA4Cuj3BG1AeweYKxUTIhzRu4g1beVwBVdcHljcQWClEvlg70eGtAWfV8ZAKADUUcGtUF-Pxj0nIcFCwLAEEnB4qyQFC0IHB5oAoGAuAnCC4D3LBICgQjiLwgoAC9uGQDCCgANgAZgATgADgiABGAoYNrBAGDXSdeJgqBkAQetBQYVAaXiTEwAQmckGELVcAIYhSEoag6DwBhmDYckRCzOBTUo+AoBRKx-igPh9jgVSuQieULPTaysFs+zHNUxlQCAA)